# Why can kotlin coroutines operate UI elements on another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying kotlinx.coroutines (version: 1.2.0). Here is a simple test code block:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
  Logger.i("${Thread.currentThread()}, ${Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()}")
  text_view.text = "test"
}
```

The printed log is:

```
Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main], false
```

As the log shows, we are not on the Android main thread, i.e UI thread. However, the code above won't throw an exception after we set text to `text_view` on this worker thread, and "test" is set to `text_view` correctly. What's the reason?

**Update 1:**

Adding `delay(10000L)` before `setText()` will cause the exception while shorter time (like 1000L in my test for a debug run with cold startup) won't. So it seems like an Android issue. But still that question, what's the reason?

**Update 2:**

Now I realized this behavior is related to Android instead of kotlinx.coroutines. The code above is executed in `onCreate()` when `ViewRootImpl` may not have called `performTraversals()` or initialize all `View`s. In this situation, `checkThread()` before UI operation isn't called, either.

Comment: You'll need to provide main thread from `Dispatcher` which will make it run on main thread.

Comment: That is not the question, right? He is asking why this behaviour is possible.

Comment: @ywwynm Are you using a ```CorountineScope```?

Comment: @BramSinke No. I'm using just the code I show above.

Comment: So, after **Update 2:** looks like you've found out answer right?

Comment: @JeelVankhede Yes. But I'm afraid that you still misunderstood the default behavior of `launch`.

Comment: Can you point me out on which concept I'm misunderstood? I'm also learning Coroutines still, it'll help me improve my knowledge.

Comment: Keep one more thing in mind: the primary role of the dispatcher is to provide a thread for the coroutine to resume on. Before the first suspension point, the so-called _initial continuation_ can run on the calling thread regardless of the dispatcher in effect. This behavior is not the default one due to some subtle issues, but you can get it with `launch(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED)` (a deprecated option).

Answer (score 0):

The default dispatcher, that is used when **coroutines** are launched in `GlobalScope`, is represented by **`Dispatchers.Default`** and uses shared background pool of threads, so **`launch(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }`** uses the same dispatcher as `GlobalScope.launch { ... }`.

Hence, When `launch { ... }` is used without parameters, it inherits the **context** *(and thus dispatcher)* from the `CoroutineScope` that it is being launched from.

In this case, it inherits the context of the main thread.

---

So, unless we define **context & dispatcher**, Coroutine will work on main thread creating new worker thread from `DefaultDispatcher` *(in our case is main again)*.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you're right. Please see my first update for the question.

Comment: Can you please refer here? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#dispatchers-and-threads, Let me know if still any doubts.

Comment: I have to say that I've also tried `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` or other dispatchers or something like `newSingleThreadContext`. It's the same result. I just simplified the code for the question.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're having `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.0'` in your project also which gives you access to *Android `Dispatchers.Main` coroutine dispatcher*.

Comment: The default dispatcher, that is used when coroutines are launched in GlobalScope, is represented by Dispatchers.Default and uses shared background pool of threads, so launch(Dispatchers.Default) { ... } uses the same dispatcher as GlobalScope.launch { ... }.

Comment: "Hence, When launch { ... } is used without parameters, it inherits the context (and thus dispatcher) from the CoroutineScope that it is being launched from." This statement is true, but not when you launch via the GlobalScope which @ywwynm is doing.

Comment: @BramSinke GlobalScope takes `Dispatchers.Unconfined` as default meaning same I guess.

Comment: @JeelVankhede So the statement is true, my bad. The result is however that the ```GlobalScope.launch { }``` will not run on the main thread, do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Kotlin coroutines really.

Even though you should not be calling UI functions from non-UI threads, not every Android UI function actually checks that you're on the UI thread. `TextView#setText()` is one of them and you can get away with calling it from a background thread without getting an exception.

Comment: No. `TextView#setText()` will also be checked.

Comment: @ywwynm Are you sure? I can't find it in the source https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java

Answer (score 0):

```
 GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            mTvText?.text = "text" // exemple: set text in main thread
            ... // write also your code here
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.